# List of labels used in google object localization

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-apis-explorer

I wonder if there is a list of the possible labels returned by google's object localization: 'human', 'dog', 'cat', etc.

Knowing all possible labels returned by the object localization service of Google, can help us use the service more efficiently. For example, if we are looking in our database for images with hats, we first send our images to the api, then we need to know all possible labels related to hat that google returned. Looking for the word "hat" in the labels will miss those images in which google object recognition returned "sombrero".

Answer (score 0):

There is no extensive list available which has all the possible labels used in [Google object localization](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer). If you feel that list would be highly beneficial you may post a feature request in [Google's issuetracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui).

In any case, notice that Google object localization results contain a machine-generated identifier (MID) corresponding to a label's [Google Knowledge Graph](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/) entry. Therefore, you may perform calls to the GKG API to check similar possible results.

For example, if you perform the call for *Sombrero*

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=sombrero&key=<yourAPIKey>&limit=5&indent=True
```

you will obtain the results: *Sombrero, Hat, Sun Hat, Sombrero Galaxy, Straw Hat*.